# No such property: variantConfiguration for class:

Tags: android, gradle, migration

After upgrading gradle 4.0.0 app build failed with error message:

**No such property: variantConfiguration for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantData**

is there any way to migrate gradle ?

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            def buildType = variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name
            ...

        }
    }
```

app level gradle file

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In the last `gradle` Relase `ApplicationVariant` implement `BaseVariant`

Instead of

```
def buildType = variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name
```

Should be

```
def buildType = variant.buildType.name
```

Comment: Updating this property signed APK signature mismatched. Did anyone encounter this problem?