# flutter set version name in apk filename

Tags: android, flutter

I tried many options in `android/app/build.gradle`

but none seems to be working.

for example I tried with below code in default config block

```
archivesBaseName = "AppName-${versionName}-${new Date().format('yyMMdd')}"
```

all example seems to be not related to flutter.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this in your gradle file

```
  buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                    variant.outputs.all {
                        def appName = "your_app_name_"
                        def buildType = variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name
                        def newName
                        if (buildType == 'debug'){
                            newName = "app-${variant.getFlavorName()}-debug.apk"
                        } else {
                            newName = "${appName}${defaultConfig.versionName}_${variant.getFlavorName()}.apk"
                        }
                        outputFileName = newName
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62075122/no-such-property-variantconfiguration-for-class

Answer (score 2):

This code works with regular builds and flavors.

Add it in the build.gradle (the source is https://stackoverflow.com/a/58392819/7198006)

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def builtType = variant.buildType.name
        def versionName = variant.versionName
        def versionCode = variant.versionCode
        def flavor = variant.flavorName
        outputFileName = "app-${flavor}-${builtType}-${versionName}-${versionCode}.apk"
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can open pubspec.yaml and search on version and edit it

Version: 1.0.0+1

Comment: this doesn't change the generated file name.

Comment: you mean the apk name ?

Comment: perfect ! search about AndroidManifest.xml  file and change android:label value with the new app name you want

Comment: it's already there, my custom `myapp-name`, but the generated file name is like this - `app-arm64-v8a-release.apk` whereas I want like - `myapp-name-v1.03`